# поиск на Си курс CS50

Tags: c, search

помогите пожалуйста выбивает ошибку при компиляции: 
error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    if (value > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (values[i] == value)
                    return true;

            }// TODO: implement a searching algorithm
    }
    else
        return false;
}// error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
```

Answer (score 2):

Что будет, если цикл `for` дойдет до конца, а значение не будет найдено? Выход из цикла, из `if`, из функции... при этом **ничего не возвращая**.

Ошибка понятна?

**Update**

Я бы делал так:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] == value)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Если у вас гарантированно нет значений меньше нуля - ну, тогда можно перед циклом добавить

```
if (value < 0) return false;
```

но, откровенно говоря, тогда уж лучше иметь массив типа `unsigned`..

Comment: Я понимаю так: если при переборе масива  values[i] == value - выводит true, если не найдет ничего ничего и не выведет. Если значение value меньше 0 тогда віведет False

Comment: не могу понять я с этим выводом

Comment: @Igor функция с типом `bool` не имеет права возвращать "ничего". В этом и ошибка

Answer (score 2):

У вас возможно три различных случая:

1. `value > 0` и значение найдено. В этом случае вы возвращаете `true`:

   ```
   if (value > 0)
       ...
           if (values[i] == value)
               return true;
   ```
2. `value < 0`. Вы возвращаете `false`:

   ```
   if (value > 0)
   ...
   else
       return false;
   ```
3. `value > 0` и значение **не** найдено. В этом случае вы ничего не возвращаете! По этому компилятор вас об этом и предупреждает:

   ```
   if (value > 0)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           {
               if (values[i] == value)
                   return true;

           }
       // value > 0, но значение не найдено!
       // Из функции ничего не возвращается, а такого быть не должно. Здесь нужно вернуть false:
       // return false;
   }
   ```

### Update

А можно просто убрать `else` в вашем коде.

Comment: после return true; ставлю else  return false и все равно выбивает ошибку. Может я что-то не так понимаю

Comment: Тогда у вас будет выводит `false` если хотя-бы один элемент массива не равен `value`. Просто уберите слово `else` из вашего кода.